# List of database of clinical trials

Tags: data-request, medical

I'd like to have a big list of database of clinical trials, both general and of pharmaceutical industries.

I know

- https://clinicaltrials.gov/
- https://www.clinicaltrialsregister.eu
- http://apps.who.int/trialsearch/

any others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OpenTrials](http://opentrials.net/) is building a database of all the data on all clinical trials.  As part of that work, we've created a [Data Package](http://frictionlessdata.io/guides/data-package/) of Clinical Trials registers here: https://github.com/opentrials/registers

Here's the CSV:

https://github.com/opentrials/registers/blob/master/data/registers.csv